Django Allauth Instagram Authentication: Invalid Redirect URI Error
I'm integrating Instagram as a third-party login option into my Django app using Django Allauth. I've set up an Instagram Basic Display API app and configured ngrok to provide my website with an HTTPS scheme. Additionally, I've set up the redirect URIs for authorization, deauthorization, and deletion in the Instagram app settings as shown in the images below:
app configuration picture
redirect uris
i also created an Instagram test user and accept it from the instagram apps and websites page
instagram test users
In my Django project's settings.py, I've configured Allauth to use the Instagram provider with the following setup:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
    },
    'instagram': {
        'APPS': [
            {
                'client_id': '463389002.....',
                'secret': 'd34b120.....',
                'redirect_uri': 'https://6112-196-179-81-60.ngrok-free.app/account/oauth/instagram/login/callback/',
            },
        ],
        'SCOPE': [
            'user_profile',
        ],
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'https://6112-196-179-81-60.ngrok-free.app',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1:8000',
    '6112-196-179-81-60.ngrok-free.app',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'https://6112-196-179-81-60.ngrok-free.app',
]

My urlpatterns in urls.py are configured as follows:
urlpatterns = [
         path('account/oauth/', include('allauth.urls')),
]

On my home.html page, I've included the Instagram authentication URL as follows:
{% load socialaccount %}
<div>
    <form id="instagram_form" action="{% provider_login_url 'instagram' %}?next=/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    <a href="javascript:instagram_auth()"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <script>
        const instagram_form = document.querySelector('#instagram_form');
        function instagram_auth() {
            instagram_form.submit()
        }
    </script>
</div>

I've successfully used Google in the authentication process with redirect URIs 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/oauth/google/login/callback/' and 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'. However, when I click on the Instagram authentication button, the browser redirects me to 'https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/third_party/error/?message=Invalid%20Request%3A%20Request%20parameters%20are%20invalid%3A%20Invalid%20redirect_uri' with the error content 'Invalid Request: Request parameters are invalid: Invalid redirect_uri'.
error picture
I tried everything from the allauth documentation, from other sites, from YouTube, from chatgpt, and the other questions related to this issue but none of them resolved the problem. see the pictures to understand more about the issue and the steps I did.
Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What is the point of that form submission supposed to be? What is the form action there - is that the Instagram Login URL, that you are supposed to send the user to?
